# Numpy: Add Rows of Matrix over another Matrix of different dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices

```
A = np.array(
    [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]])

B = np.array(
    [[1,1,1],
     [2,2,2]])
```

I would like to have a matrix, which is 3x3x2 which is [[A + first row of B], [A + second row of B]]

```
C = np.array(
    [[[2,3,4],
      [5,6,7],
      [8,9,10]],
     [[3,4,5],
      [6,7,8],
      [9,10,11]]])
```

I'm aware that I could do np.concatenate((A + B[0], A + B[1])), but I won't know how many rows B contains beforehand and for my own programming experience I'm curious if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `A =` and `B =` commands don't generate matrices, but lists of lists.  The difference matters because they don't have numpy's nice vector math attached.

Anyway, you could expand `A` by creating a new axis using `[:,None]`, do the addition, and then swap the axes to get the shape you want:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> B = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2]])
>>> (A[:, None] + B).swapaxes(0,1)
array([[[ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

Note that this has shape (2,3,3), not (3,3,2), but that's the shape your C had, so I went with that.

Comment: Ah, yes I didn't meant to imply I was using lists instead of numpy arrays. Your solution is very nice, I will have to add creating of new axes and reshaping to my numpy arsenal. Thanks!